# Trunks.js Drawer Menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, drawer

Can someone point me to a nice drawer menu with jquery tutorial. I am trying to use a Trunk.js plugin which is very nice, but i ran into a problem. If i place the slider into body content it scolls on top of the fixed nav-bar rather than underneath of it. Sample here:

[Link Here](Http://www.mareksvoicehs.info/sts/)

Maybe someone can help me to fix this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide us with your sample please?

This sounds like a z-index problem. Try setting the z-index of your nav-bar to 999.

```
z-index:999;
```

If that won't work, lower the z-index of the slideshow, might be that you'd have to use a '!important' for that. But you'll find that out.

```
z-index:1 !imporant;
```

EDIT 2:
My apologies, z-index:998 on line 35 of trunk.css, z-index:999 on line 70 of trunk.css

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp for more info on z-indexes.

Comment: I tried z-index: 999 that worked for a slider on normal screen size, but when resized down to mobile phone, the drawer is sitting on top of other conent. There is a link http://mareksvoicehs.info/sts/